# how to use genetic algorithm in wireless sensor network

Tags: networkx, sensors, genetic-algorithm

i want to implement genetic algorithm in Wireless sensor network to optimize the deployment of the sensors in a zone, so the minimum of sensors cover the maximum of targets, can anyone please help in any way, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a GA where your decision variables are the position of each sensor.

If you have `n` sensors, your chromosome would have `n * dimensions` elements, e.g., if you have to define for each sensor its `x` and `y` position your chromosome would have `n * 2` elements.

So given this vector (chromosome) that defines the position of each sensor you just have to define a function that computes the coverage given the position of the sensors. In this way, you can compute the fitness function of every chromosome (compute the solution given by the chromosome).